# Eclipse error: 'Selection does not contain a main type/an applet'

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know very similar questions are already there, however I am a beginner to Java/Selenium WebDriver, and had originally created this in Selenium IDE, and then exported it as *Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver* and was hoping to get specific help, as I wasn't sure of exactly where I was going wrong. When I run as *Java Application* I get the error *Selection does not contain a main type* and when I run as *Java Applet* I get the error *Selection does not contain an applet*. Here is my code:

```
package com.exports.tests;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Login {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.example.co.uk/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/123example/index.jsp");
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [getEval | prompt("Username: ") | ]]
    driver.findElement(By.name("LoginText1")).clear();
    element.sendKeys(user input);
    //driver.findElement(By.name("LoginText1")).clear();
    //driver.findElement(By.name("LoginText1")).sendKeys(_username);
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [getEval | prompt("Password: ") | ]]
    driver.findElement(By.name("password1")).clear();
    element.sendKeys(user input);
    //driver.findElement(By.name("password1")).clear();
    //driver.findElement(By.name("password1")).sendKeys(_password);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"Login\"]")).click();
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [windowFocus |  | ]]
    driver.switchTo().window("CarrierNet Desktop");
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alert.getText();
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Any help is greatly appreciated.**

Comment: well, to run this, it should contain `public static void main(String args[])` method which it does not. To "run" this you have to run the TEST. But I dont know how to do it exactly in Eclipse

Comment: @PavelJanicek where would I add that, `public static void main(String args[])`?

Comment: @Perception How would you run it as a jUnit test, as when I try to do so, it asks to onfigure it, but I don't know what to put.

Comment: @D.Shah - you're saying Eclipse is asking you to configure jUnit? What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @Perception I am running Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Juno Service Release 2. Build ID: 20130225-0426. I downloaded it a few days ago from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of running it as a java application.

Run it as a JUNIT Test.

Comment: I managed to do that now, but get the error '_No JUnit tests found_'.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on HemChe's answer (which set me on the right track):

Add the JUnit and Selenium .jar file locations to your classpath, then set the path to your webdriver (so Selenium knows how to control a browser), then call the JUnit runner with your class as the parameter.  This is how it looks on my linux commandline

```
cd /path/to/my/compiled/class
java -classpath .:/path/to/junit/classes/*:/path/to/selenium/classes/* -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/path/to/geckodriver org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MyTestClass
```

and like magic, a Firefox window opens up and runs your test, with errors in the console.

The Selenium classpath should have the file client-combined-x.x.x-nodeps.jar
The JUnit classpath should have lots of files, including junit-x.xx.jar